# Error in phpldapadmin on Ubuntu 18.04 "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare password_hash() in ...../lib/functions.php on line 2236"

Tags: ldap, openldap, phpldapadmin

Until writing this question, there is no entry for "Php LDAP Admin" on the Ubuntu 18.04 repositories. I had to install and deploy it manually as a php program. I did this, but unfortunately, I faced this error:

`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare password_hash() in ..../phpldapadmin/lib/functions.php on line 2236`

I checked the code either with phpv5.6 and phpv7.2; the error remains same as above.

Any idea?

Comment: Sounds like the code you're trying to run is exceedingly old and hasn't been updated to run on any PHP version newer than 5.5...

Comment: Thanks @ircmaxell :) 
You are right. I have a plan to port a new branch on project which will work on Ubuntu 18.04 and on newer version php. Before that, I am trying to prepare a "Patch" for project.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, the best solution for the short-time is using the project under the Ubuntu 16.04. When you install the phpLDAPadmin from Ubuntu 16.04 repositories, it automatically checks for php7.0 and installs it if it does not exist.

On Ubuntu 18.04, there is no entry for phpLDAPadmin yet, but with some efforts may you could deploy the code with php7.0. Furthermore, it could be beneficial to check following link, to patch some major bugs and also update phpLDAPadmin from v1.2.2 to v1.2.3:

http://www.jouvinio.net/wiki/index.php/PhpLDAPAdmin_Update_Version_1.2.2_vers_1.2.3